# 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I get this error when creating a new product. This is the function:

```
public function createProduct(Request $request) {
    $product = Product::create($request->all());
    $product->title = strip_tags($request->title);
    $product->description = strip_tags($request->description);
    $product->price = strip_tags($request->price);

    $product->category_id = 1;
    $product->save();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

'insert into `products` (`title`, `description`, `price`, `image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

But why I can't see `category_id` between these values ? I also made `category_id` fillable in Product.php

```
protected $fillable = [
    'slug', 'title', 'description', 'stock', 'price', 'image',
    'category_id'
];
```

And I've also created `category` in `categories` table with an ID of 1

Can someone help ?

Comment: If you're using a framework, let us know which (I'm guessing Laravel)?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, it's Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you create and save the model before you set the category_id.  Your request data must not have a category ID.

```
$product = Product::create($request->all());
```

This will attempt to insert the row (create+save the model) into the database using the data you pass to it.

So by the time you hit:

```
$product->title = strip_tags($request->title);
```

Your insert query has already been sent.  For readability sake, don't mix create or make with setters.  Either do:

```
$product = Product::create([
   'category_id' => 1,
   ...
]);
```

Or do:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->category_id = 1;
...
$product->save();
```